# Error in QuantumUtils in Mathematica

Tags: documentation

I installed QuantumUtils, but when I am running

```
Needs["QuantumUtils`"]

RunAllTest[]
```

I have following error:

> ```
> LindbladSolver:ODESolver.Numeric:   Error
> LindbladSolver:ODESolver.Symbolic:  Error
> LindbladSolver:SchrodingerSolver.Numeric:   Error
> LindbladSolver:SchordingerSolver.Symbolic:  Error
> LindbladSolver:LindbladSolver.Numeric:  Error
> LindbladSolver:LindbladSolver.Symbolic: Error
> LindbladSolver:LindbladSolver.QuantumChannel:   Error
> 233 of 240 unit tests passed.
> ```

I couldn't understand the problem.

Thank you.